# Copying numbers from PARI/GP

Tags: pari

I have a problem, for which there probably is an easy solution.

Suppose, I have calculated a large number in PARI/GP, lets say, 10,000 digits
long.

I want to copy this number in a normal text file, such that it can be copied
back to PARI/GP.

The problem is, that the program does not avoid (hidden) new-line-marks, so if
I copy the number back, it cannot be read by PARI. The print1-command does
not help either.

I had two non-satisfactionary ideas :

1) Copying in an editor, using the backspace-key to remove the (hidden) new-line-marks, which only works upto some length.

2) Extending the allowed length of a line, but then I cannot
easily and fast mark the number, which is no problem with the normal lentgh 80.

> How can I avoid the new-line-marks in the output in PARI/GP ?

Comment: Did you try to use the command 'write(F, str)' allowing to push a custom string 'str' into a custom file 'F'? For example, you can construct your own PARI-readable string like 'Str("{", <your variable>, "}")'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Piotr already gave the answer in a comment. Suppose you have:

```
n = 1<<33216
```

or any other number. Then if you use:

```
write("MySavedNumber.txt", n)
```

things will be fine. No new-lines in the middle of the text file.

When you need to recover the number in another session of PARI/GP, simply use:

```
n = read("MySavedNumber.txt")
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried .txt, but I did not know that the " 's are necessary.