# How can I copy a large number from pari/gp into yafu to find factors?

Tags: copy-paste, pari

Here :

[Copying numbers from PARI/GP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634395/copying-numbers-from-pari-gp)

I learnt how I can write a large number in PARI/GP and recover it. This works fine. But a new problem arises : I have a large number (13 653 digits) in a file and want to copy it in yafu in order to find factors. But apparently because of the length of the number, yafu cannot read the number properly. Seems that still the file contains a hidden format preventing the file to be exported to another program.

What can I do ?

Comment: Why not to find factors just in PARI/GP?

Comment: @PiotrSemenov I do not know how to search for single factors in PARI with ECM. PARI/GP supports ECM, but it only gives an output if the factorization is completed. Furthermore, yafu is faster than PARI/GP.

Comment: I do not know what yafu wants. In Pari, when you use `write`, you get a plain ASCII file that terminates with a newline (CR LF, at least on my system). If you use `write1` instead, you get no such newline. Not sure if this is your solution; however, there is no "hidden format" otherwise.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Thanks for the tip, but still I can't copy the number :(

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected format of YAFU:

yafu-x64.exe factor(65453637459381111885198811211520302619172225361929424640503140562028284452523012121811111413242229967855624960451829383537598953548575881828345547330346069889322777641187811213598110111128995243111123109129752061651201762002867) -threads 4 -ecm_path ..\ecm\ecm.exe -ggnfs_dir ..\ggnfs\